# Why does calling this variable miss out the array it's contained in?

Tags: reactjs

In the online tutorial for React you are guided through creating a tic tac toe game with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square 
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        history: [{
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
        }],
        stepNumber:0,
        xIsNext: true,
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if(calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
        return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
        history: history.concat([{
            squares:squares,
        }]),
        stepNumber: history.length,
        xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    }); 
  }
  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      return(
        <li key={move}>
          <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
        </li>
      );
    });

    let status;
    if(winner){
        status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else{
        if(this.state.stepNumber === 9){
            status = 'Draw!';
        } else{
        status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
        }
    }

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board 
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
      if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
        return squares[a];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

My question here is fairly simple. In the Board class, when calling `this.props.squares[i]`. Why do we miss out the history array that squares is located in? Shouldn't this call be `this.props.history.squares[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down to the declarations you're using with some variables:

```
const history = [{ squares: Array(9).fill(null) }]
// history = [{ squares: [null, null, null, ...] }]
const current = history[0]
// current = { squares: [null, null, null, ...] }
```

And now to `Board` you are passing:

```
<Board
  squares = {current.squares}
  // squares = [null, null, null, ...]
```

So essentially, you are only passing down an `Array` to your props and can access it by `this.props.squares[i]`

If you wanted to use `this.props.history.squares[i]` , first you should have used `this.props.history[step].squares[i]` (both `history` and `squares` are Arrays), and second - you should have passed

```
// Game
  <Board 
    squares = {history}
    ...
```